# Force WPF scrollbar to only land on integer values

Tags: .net, wpf, scrollbar

If I have a WPF scroll bar with both `Change` properties defined, why is it still possible to have a real value like `123.456` that is not a multiple of my steps?

```
<ScrollBar Minimum="-5000" Maximum="5000" SmallChange="1" LargeChange="25"></ScrollBar>
```

Is there a way to force a scroll bar to only set values of integers, multiples of the step, or both?

Most of the existing documentation on this issue seems directed towards WPF Sliders (which can use `IsSnapToTickEnabled`) or ScrollViewers (content controls using `IScrollInfo`), neither of which have equivalent solutions in `ScrollBar`.

Comment: `ScrollViewer` derives from `System.Windows.Controls.ContentControl`. `ScrollBar`s derive from `System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.RangeBase`, same as `ProgressBar`s and `Slider`s.

Comment: The attached behavior answer still works fine. Just look at the ValueChanged event instead of ScrollChanged event.

Comment: Please submit it as an answer if you have a working implementation. I've looked at the `Behavior<>`-based solution and it won't work for a `ScrollBar`. `ScrollViewer` is a content control designed to move its children into the viewport on scroll events, whereas `ScrollBar` is simply a track + range. `ScrollBar`'s implementation is also completely different, as it has no way to use an `IScrollInfo` and a completely separate property set. They're not the same!

Comment: This isn't a duplicate. the other question mentioned isn't the same topic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you should be able to control the granularity of the stepping through a behavior. The endpoints (min and max) are the trickiest, but I'll stub out the rough idea here:

Attached Behavior:

```
public class StepScrollBehavior : Behavior<ScrollBar>
{
    protected override void OnAttached()
    {
        AssociatedObject.ValueChanged += AssociatedObject_ValueChanged;
        base.OnAttached();
    }

    protected override void OnDetaching()
    {
        AssociatedObject.ValueChanged -= AssociatedObject_ValueChanged;
        base.OnDetaching();
    }
    private void AssociatedObject_ValueChanged(object sender, 
            System.Windows.RoutedPropertyChangedEventArgs<double> e)
    {
        var scrollBar = (ScrollBar)sender;
        var newvalue = Math.Round(e.NewValue, 0);
        if (newvalue > scrollBar.Maximum)
            newvalue = scrollBar.Maximum;
        // feel free to add code to test against the min, too.
        scrollBar.Value = newvalue;
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
    <ScrollBar Minimum="-5000" Maximum="5000">
        <i:Interaction.Behaviors>
            <local:StepScrollBehavior/>
        </i:Interaction.Behaviors>
    </ScrollBar>
```

Comment: It's unclear to me if we need to set `e.Handled = true;` in the ValueChanged event. We may need to, or it may get us in trouble.